# Understanding group and or in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm looking for words like "one year", "two years", "2-3 years" or "3 - 4 years" in a long string. I've tried to do it using regular expressions. But I'm not sure that I got it when groups are involved.

Let's see what I mean:

```py
import re

text = 'one year, honey 2-5 year, dressed six, ten'
pattern = r'(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten| \
                  eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen| \
                  eighteen|nineteen|twenty|[0-9]+[- ]*[0-9]*)[+ ]*year?'

re.findall(pattern, text)  # ['one', '2-5']
```

My problem is that I want `['one year', '2-5 years']`. I'm not sure how to do it. If I forgot about the numbers in words:

```py
pattern = r'[0-9]+[- ]*[0-9]*[\+ ]*year?'
re.findall(pattern, text)  # ['2-5 years']
```

Why I got `years` in the second and not in the first? How I can modify it to got years in the first one?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `[0-9]+[- ]*[0-9]*` must be the first element in the alternation list

Comment: Why is there a question mark after the 'r'? Don't you mean `years?` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the pattern to match the numbers first. Here is an example:

```py
>>> pattern = r'''(?x)\b(?:[0-9]+(?:[- ]*[0-9]+)?|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten
|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty)
[+ ]*years?\b'''
>>> re.findall(pattern, text)
['one year', '2-5 year']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/as88Jo) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EdpLh/2).

*Details*

- `(?x)` - `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` inline modifier
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[0-9]+(?:[- ]*[0-9]+)?` - one or more digits followed with zero or more spaces or `-` and then one or more digits
  - `|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty` - one of the words in the alternation list
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `[+ ]*` - zero or more `+` or spaces
- `years?` - `year` or `years`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: @Xbel Also matches "I bought a phone years ago".

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression, `year?` should be `years?` because it's the final "s" which is optional, not the "r". You also need to use so called *non-capturing groups* `(?: ... )` to get the string matched by the whole regular expression; otherwise you will only get the strings matched by the parenthesized subexpressions.

For improved readability it's also a good idea to divide a long regular expression into subexpressions and give them meaningful names. Try this:

```
import re

text = 'one year, honey 2-5 year, dressed six, ten'
numberWordsRe = r'one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty'
numberOrIntervalRe=r'\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)'
pattern = r'\b(?:' + numberWordsRe + r'|' + numberOrIntervalRe + r')\s+years?\b'

print re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Comment: Those are clarifying comments. Tanks a lot.